addEventListener does not work correctly in the loop
<template>
  <span :data-target="target" class="input-icon">
    <slot></slot>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputIcon",
  props: {
    target: String,
  },
  mounted() {
    let showHidePassword = function (selector) {
      let elem = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      elem.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let target = document.getElementById(
            item.getAttribute("data-target")
          );
          if (target.type == "password") {
            target.type = "text";
            item.classList.add("shown");
          } else {
            target.type = "password";
            item.classList.remove("shown");
          }
        });
      });
    };

    showHidePassword(".password-toggle");
  },
};
</script>

I have this code. It works, but if elem is not an even number, i.e. if there are 1 or 3 of them on the page. With an even number it doesn't work because the loop goes through it twice, which causes the class to be added and removed at the same time.
JS code written here works correctly in vanilla js, but this error occurs in vue 3.
I tried all possible variants that I knew, but it didn't work. What is my problem?

The code in your question shouldn't be ran more than once. Are you running showHidePassword more than once? possibly on some event or loop? redundant event bindings aren't ideal.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

When you have even elements that leads to the class being added and removed in quick succession, resulting in no visible change.
So this might be a quick fix to toggle the class based on the current state of the target element outside of the loop
This should work, please let me know if it works for you
This code is to show password for each input you click on show not all at once
<input type="password" id="password1">
<span class="password-toggle" data-target="password1">Show/Hide Password</span><br>

    <script>
    let showHidePassword = function(selector) {
    let elem = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    elem.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = document.getElementById(item.getAttribute("data-target"));
            if (target.type === "password") {
                target.type = "text";
            } else {
                target.type = "password";
            }
            // Toggle class based on the current state of the target element
            item.classList.toggle("shown");
        });
    });
}

// Call the showHidePassword function with the appropriate selector
showHidePassword('.password-toggle');
 </script>


Only one result occurs between an if statements if and else. There was no case of classes being added and removed in quick succession here.

@KevinB can you repeat that i cannot seem to understand  your statement

Moving the classList change outside of the if statement will have no effect whatsoever on the problem the op is having because only one condition is true; either it is of type password or it isn't. If anything it may actually cause other problems, since you swapped it to toggle

@KevinB you are actually correct i just tested that and i will edit the answer to a working one.

@KevinB I have just updated a new code that is currently working for me in a test file, where i have 4 input fields all passwords and on each one i click to show Password it works for it. Please let me know if there are any other mistakes i should check out, i am new to giving people help haha <3 .

see, what I think the problem is the op is calling showHidePassword more times than once. You can test this by trying it yourself, if you call it twice, your code won't work. if you call it 3 times, it will, 4 times it wont, etc, just as the op has described.

@KevinB as i said i just tested it with 4 inputs and doing them one by one and it is working for each one.
We have input1,2,3,4
On input 1 i click show password it shows
then i do for 2,3,4 one by one and they work

No, not the number of inputs, call the function itself twice. showHidePassword('.password-toggle');showHidePassword('.password-toggle');. Your "quick succession" is partially right, just your explanation for why it's occurring isn't and the fix is irrelevant to the actual problem.

This is an X/Y problem. if you call the op's code once, it works just fine like yours.

Hmmm, I have tested and added some console.log outputs for confirmations and only when i click the toggle it logs out only call of function and it works how it is supposed like the question, if I am not mistaken he wants to show one by one not with one button to show all passwords

@KevinB and no need for vote downs if we try to help and actually make a working code for his issue. Thanks

I only downvote incorrect answers. this answer doesn't work any better than the op's code. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lugv12ey/

Thanks for your answers, but it turns out I asked the wrong question. The code I provided earlier was written in the Vue 3 framework. I just thought it was an error related to simple js code. I didn't think it was related to Vue js.
